# Oracle JOIN operation performance changes when swapping SELECT statements

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-execution-plan

I came across the following behavior while studying Oracle query parsing and performance. I used following query for that,

```
SELECT 1 
FROM USER_PROCEDURES 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = SUBSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ), 1, INSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info'), '.' ) - 1 ) 
AND PROCEDURE_NAME = SUBSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ), INSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ),'.' ) + 1 ) 
UNION 
SELECT 1 
FROM USER_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info') 
AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```

The explain plan for the above query is as follows,

[image]

Now I changed the query into the following format [ Swap the SELECT statements],

```
SELECT 1 
FROM USER_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info') 
AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
UNION 
SELECT 1 
FROM USER_PROCEDURES 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = SUBSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ), 1, INSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info'), '.' ) - 1 ) 
AND PROCEDURE_NAME = SUBSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ), INSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ),'.' ) + 1 ) ;
```

Corresponding explain plan is as follows,

[image]

There is a significant different between the cost of operations. This could be a pretty basic thing but since I'm new to Oracle [or any DB stuff] this is a puzzle for me. Hope you could help me to figure this behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not use bind variables like `:B1` while executing an `explain plan` statement. Bind variables fool the optimizer as their values are absolutely unknown. Please replace `:B1` with a sample value that you'd use and take the `explain plan` output and post it here.

Comment: I updated the post as you've requested. However the explain plan output was similar.

Comment: Interesting problem, it's unusual for the order of the query blocks to affect the plan.  The problem can likely be simplified, the plans are different even with these two very simple queries: `SELECT 1 FROM USER_PROCEDURES UNION SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;` and `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 1 FROM USER_PROCEDURES;`.

Comment: Yes indeed.. Could the structure of view USER_PROCEDURES be the reason???

Answer (score 5):

**Oracle 12c:**

The function `NO_ROOT_SW_FOR_LOCAL` in `USER_PROCEDURES` appears to be the cause of the difference.

In general, changing the order of things like predicates, tables in the `FROM` clause, or query blocks in a `UNION` statement has no meaningful effect on execution plans.
 With `UNION`, some of the subplans may be flipped around but the total cost will be the same.

For this specific case, first simplify the statements to these:

```
explain plan for select 1 from user_procedures union select 1 from dual;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

explain plan for select 1 from dual union select 1 from user_procedures;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

The two sub-execution plans are not merely switched, they are significantly changed and the totals are different.  As with most data dictionary queries, the plans are large and the 266 lines of output are not displayed here.

The source code of `USER_PROCEDURES` contains the odd code  `... from NO_ROOT_SW_FOR_LOCAL(INT$DBA_PROCEDURES) ...`.  The plan difference goes away when  `NO_ROOT_SW_FOR_LOCAL` is removed.

I have no idea what that function does and I cannot find any references it.  Nothing in DBA_OBJECTS, DBA_SOURCE, support.oracle.com, or even Google. This is as far as we can dig without any serious hacking.  If this cost difference is an issue then you will need to raise a service request with Oracle.

**11g:**

?

Comment: Thanx for your answer. But I'm having a hard time locating the code segment you have mentioned in USER_PROCEDURES [11g DB].

Comment: Sorry, my answer only applies to 12c, the code in 11g is different.  I can reproduce the issue there, but I cannot simplify the code nearly as much.  It may take a while to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but I would try rewriting the query to avoid the need to always execute both parts:

```
select 1
from   dual
where exists (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM USER_OBJECTS 
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME = UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info') 
        AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE') or
      exists (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM USER_PROCEDURES 
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME = SUBSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ), 1, INSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info'), '.' ) - 1 ) 
        AND PROCEDURE_NAME = SUBSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ), INSTR( UPPER('Client_Sys.Clear_Info' ),'.' ) + 1 ));
```

Comment: Think this would be a great alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle 11G:**

In my opinion or what I have see so far, UNION or VIEW statements process more rows but with negligible overhead. 
Also just comparing the cost of the plan will not give you the best plan even though they are two different queries fired on the same time, same DB, and same settings etc
It is just an indicating factor and induces the observor effect.

When you run those two queries, did you find any big change in execution time? I found NOTHING.

But if you ask why there is a difference in the cost while swapping, here is my two cents.

```
On plan 1, Cost was 161, CPU cost was 74M, IO Cost was 151
On plan 2, Cost was 161, CPU cost was 23M, IO Cost was 6
```

I found no difference in processing the selects while swapping, but the UNION is the point where the plan differs. 
As I said above, the cost difference is due to additional row processing on UNION and VIEW.

Comment: Well for some users the execution time differs and for some it doesn't. This is basically due to the records accessible for different users. 
So, I think what you have mentioned could be the reason.